# SQL - use only clients that are present in all months

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a dataset with different clients, and their sales count. Over time, some clients get added and deleted from the data. How do I make sure that when I look at the sales counts, that I am only using a selection of the clients that were in the data set all the time? Ie if I have a client that doesn't have a record for 2018-03, then I don't want that client to be part of the entire query. If a clients does not have a record in 2020-03, then I also do not want this client to be part of the entire query.

For example,  the following query:

```
select DATE_PART (y, sold_date)as year, DATE_PART (mm, sold_date) as month, count(distinct(client))
from sales_data
where sold_date > '2018-01-01' 
group by year, month 
order by year,month
```

Yields

```
year    month   count
2018    1   78
2018    2   83
2018    3   80
2018    4   83
2018    5   84
2018    6   81
2018    7   83
2018    8   90
2018    9   89
2018    10  95
2018    11  94
2018    12  97
2019    1   102
2019    2   103
2019    3   102
2019    4   105
2019    5   103
2019    6   104
2019    7   104
2019    8   106
2019    9   106
2019    10  108
2019    11  109
2019    12  104
2020    1   104
2020    2   102
2020    3   103
2020    4   98
2020    5   97
2020    6   79
```

So I want to only use the clients that are in all months, they should not be more than 78, because there can not be more users than the minimal month (2018-1).

FYI, I am using Amazon Redshift here but I am OK with a query that's rdbms agnostic or works for SQL-Server/Oracle/MySQL/PostgreSQL, I am just interested in a pattern on how to solve this issue effectively.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: So, if you have a client that doesn't have a record for 2018-03-02, then you don't want that client to be part of the query? Or is it just for the month of 2018-03? Or the client just have to be there in 2018-01 and also at 2020-06, but it's OK if they're missing in March? What does "they should not be more than 78" mean? You only have 78 in total now, or limit the query to max 78 on every row?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it was more of a conceptual question which is why I did not tag the specific product, but for this specific project I am using Amazon Redshift. Will add to tag if that helps.

Comment: @Scratte I meant that they should not be more than 78 rows because that is the min amount of rows (in the first month). So if i want to make sure all clients exist in all rows it cannot possibly be more than 78. if i have a client that  doesn't have a record for 2018-03-02, then I don't want that client to be part of the query.

Comment: That is very important and you should mention that clients have to have a record for every day in the entire period (every day is not the same as every month), not just records in every month. Because if they just have to be present in 2018-01 and still be in 2020-06 then the query is very simple.

Comment: There are a lot of users that will play with queries on online fiddles to ensure they work when they answer Questions. I do not think there is one for amazon-redshift. If you're OK with a query that's rdbms agnostic or works for SQL-Server/Oracle/MySQL/PostgreSQL, then mention that too (In the Question, because comments sometimes just vanish :)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you want correctly, and if this is just a one-off query, you could use a correlated subquery in the where clause:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_PART(y, s.sold_date) AS year,
    DATE_PART(mm, s.sold_date) AS month,
    COUNT(DISTINCT s.client)
FROM
    sales_data AS s
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT sd.client FROM sales_data AS sd WHERE DATE_PART(y, 
        sd.sold_date) = 2018 AND DATE_PART(mm, sd.sold_date) = 1 AND 
        sd.client = s.client
    ) AND
    s.sold_date > '2018-01-01' 
GROUP BY
    year,
    month 
ORDER
    DATE_PART(y, s.sold_date),
    DATE_PART(mm, s.sold_date)
```

Comment: Why do a calculation in the subquery?

Comment: It appears that they want only the clients that existed in 2018-01.

Comment: This is not entirely what I need. Sorry if I was unclear but I want to look what clients existed in each month, and if a client did not exist in a specific month, I also want to exclude them from the rest of the query.

Comment: Gotcha. You might need to use a loop, but I'm not quite sure yet...

Comment: @Ferdinand55 Even if that was true, the subquery could have been just `(select 1 from sales_data as sd where sd.client = s.client and sd.sold_date < '2018-02-01')` which is why I was puzzled by the calculation.

Comment: can you count the number of months in the period, count the number of distinct months that a client has appeared in and compare the 2?

Answer (score 0):

presence in all months can be done with 2-step aggregation:

1. group sales data by customer ID having all months
2. group sales data joined to (1) by year, month

like this (=12 can be a dynamic expression, depending on the amount of history you have)

```
with
 stable_customers as (
    select customer_id
    from sales_data
    group by 1
    having count(distinct date_trunc('month' from sold_date)=12
)
select 
 DATE_PART (y, sold_date) as year
,DATE_PART (mm, sold_date) as month,
,count(1)
from sales_date
join stable_customers
using (customer_id)
where sold_date > '2018-01-01' 
group by year, month 
order by year,month
```

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions.  Unfortunately, SQL Server does not support `count(distinct)` as a window function.  Fortunately, there is a simple work-around using `dense_rank()`:

```
select year, month, count(distinct client)
from (select sd.*, year, month,
             (dense_rank() over (order by year, month) +
              dense_rank() over (order by year desc, month desc)
             ) as num_months,
             (dense_rank() over (partition by client order by year, month) +
              dense_rank() over (partition by client order by year desc, month desc)
             ) as num_months_client
      from sales_data sd cross apply
           (values (year(sold_date), month(sold_date))) v(year, month)
      where sd.sold_date > '2018-01-01' 
     ) sd
where num_months_client = num_months
group by year, month 
order by year, month;
```

Note:  This looks at all months that are in the data.  If all clients are missing  2019-03, then that months is not considered at all.